# Counting differences in data frame R and Adding to Column

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, unique

I want to be able to compare differences by order number within a table and attach a column that states the differences. For example I want this

```
  order  color type    shape             alert
1     1   blue    a   circle             type
2     1   blue    b   circle                  
3     2  green    a   circle             color
4     2   blue    a   circle  color type shape
5     2 yellow    b triangle              type
6     2 yellow    c triangle                  
7     3 orange    c triangle
```

to look like this

```
  order  color type    shape             alert
1     1   blue    a   circle             type
2     1   blue    b   circle                  
3     2  green    a   circle             color type shape
4     2   blue    a   circle  
5     2 yellow    b triangle              
6     2 yellow    c triangle                  
7     3 orange    c triangle
```

My code only compares 2 rows that are next to each other how do I effectively compare all rows with the same order numbers? Can I avoid loops? Here is my code

```
order = c(0001, 0001, 0002, 0002, 0002, 0002, 0003) 
color = c("blue", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "orange") 
type = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c") 
shape = c("circle", "circle", "circle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle",    "triangle") 
df = data.frame(order, color, type, shape)

df$alert <- ""

for(i in 1:nrow(df)-1){
  if(identical(df$order[i+1],df$order[i])){
    if(!identical(df$color[i+1],df$color[i])){
      df$alert[i] <- paste(df$alert[i],"color")
    }
    if(!identical(df$type[i+1],df$type[i])){
      df$alert[i] <- paste(df$alert[i],"type")
    }
    if(!identical(df$shape[i+1],df$shape[i])){
      df$alert[i] <- paste(df$alert[i],"shape")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` based solution:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% gather(measure, val, -order) %>%
         group_by(order, measure) %>%
         summarise(alerts = length(unique(val))) %>%
         filter(alerts>1) %>%
         summarise(alerts = paste0(measure, collapse = " ")) %>%
         left_join(dat1, .)

  order  color type    shape           alerts
1     1   blue    a   circle             type
2     1   blue    b   circle             type
3     2  green    a   circle color type shape
4     2   blue    a   circle color type shape
5     2 yellow    b triangle color type shape
6     2 yellow    c triangle color type shape
7     3 orange    c triangle             <NA>
```